# System of equations, non-square

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra

I am currently struggling to solve a system of linear equations using python. I have tried using numpy.linalg.solve, but it seems that this will only work for square arrays, which mine are not. Is there another function that I can use to solve my system that I don't know about, or is there some different method that I should try to implement here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your system have more equations than unknowns, or the other way around? That is, you matrix has more rows than columns, or viceversa?

Comment: yes, It has 3 unknowns with 3 columns and 10 rows.

Comment: In that case, the standard way of doing it is the least squares method suggested in @peci1's answer.

Answer (score 2):

What about using the least squares method if you want to use numpy?

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html .

But it probably won't give you all solutions of an underdeterminated system.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "it probably won't give you all solutions..."?

Comment: The least squares method is an optimization problem. So it just computes an error (it evaluates the left sides with its current solutions and sums the squares of the difference between what it gets and the right side). And the algorithm tries to minimize this error. As it reaches a solution with zero error, it stops. So you get exactly one solution (if at least one exists). What is important is to say the least squares algorithms are non-deterministic, so the returned solutions may differ every run. But if you have more equations than variables, then at most 1 solution exists and you get it.

Comment: @peci1 A solution to the least squares problem Ax=b always exists, and it's unique iff the columns of A are linearly independent. Also, algorithms to solve it don't have to be iterative. Do you have an example of an algorithm that's not deterministic?

Comment: @jorgeca Almost every instance of a gradient method (e.g. the Levenberg-Marquardt method for non-linear optimization) depends on an initial guess. I think this guess is most likely to be random or randomly selected from a set of possible initial vectors. And other randomizations may be introduced in the algorithm to prevent stopping in a local extreme.

Comment: @peci1 Oh, right! That's the case for *non-linear* least squares, though. The OP has a linear least squares problem Ax=b, and its solution can be computed by calling lapack's [dgelsd](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/dgelsd.htm) routine (which is an SVD decomposition in the end), as numpy does.